# Condition Insert based Fuzzy Logic in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table as below

| Company Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Facebook | 32 |
| Google | 33 |
| Apple | 44 |

So If I get a new record with Company name "Facebook Inc" or "Facebook Company" it should ignore  else it should insert. What should be condition for logic?

insert into Table a where? (Fuzzy logic)

Comment: Can you add more examples of this fuzzy logic?

Comment: What are your rules for determining if 2 different values should be treated as the same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the logic described in the question a simple way of solving this is with a `merge`:

- Apply the "fuzzy logic" to look for a match. In this case it's a regex that compares the first word of the string: `regexp_substr(a.company, '^[^ ]+') = regexp_substr(b.company, '^[^ ]+')`
- If matched, do nothing (with `and false`).
- If not matched, insert:

```sql
merge into companies a
using (
    select 'Facebook Inc' company, 10 id
) as b on regexp_substr(a.company, '^[^ ]+') = regexp_substr(b.company, '^[^ ]+')
when matched and false then update set a.id = b.id
when not matched then insert (company, id) values (b.company, b.id)
```

Setup:

```sql
create or replace temp table companies as
select $1::string company, $2::int id
from values ('Google', 1), ('Facebook', 2), ('Apple', 3);
```

If you want to define a more complex "fuzzy logic", please start a new question.